# Use Nexus 3 API to change admin password

Tags: sonatype, nexus3

I would like to use the Nexus 3 api to change the admin default password as well as the email address using groovy. But I don't understand how to set the password using the groovy api. Can someone provide an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally thought changePassword was deprecated, but I was mistaken. Here is an example of updating admin email address and changing the password:

```
def user = security.securitySystem.getUser('admin')
user.setEmailAddress('admin@mycompany.com')
security.securitySystem.updateUser(user)
security.securitySystem.changePassword('admin','admin456')
```

Comment: How and where did you run this script ?

Comment: @Romaan this gets run by groovy script engine in NXRM https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/script-api

Comment: Thanks @SamGleske I have also provided my own answer elaborating DennisHoer answer

Answer (score 3):

## Summary

You can use the REST API to both update user information and change their password.  This includes the admin  user.

## Nexus REST API: Update user information

The default admin user-data.json in my instance is the following:

```
{
  "userId": "admin",
  "firstName": "Administrator",
  "lastName": "User",
  "emailAddress": "admin@example.org",
  "source": "default",
  "status": "active",
  "readOnly": false,
  "roles": [
    "nx-admin"
  ],
  "externalRoles": []
}
```

Update the `user-data.json` to your desired values and use `curl` with the REST API.

```
NX_PASSWORD="admin user password"

curl -ifu admin:"${NX_PASSWORD}" \
  -XPUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data "$(< user-data.json)" \
  <nexus base  URL>/service/rest/v1/security/users/admin
```

## Nexus REST API: Change password

You'll want to use the [Security Management API](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/security-management-api).

See [Nexus 3 backend source code](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/a4010c3b0d949c8041f29868d03b36bfc9171628/components/nexus-security/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/security/internal/rest/UserApiResource.java#L180-L203).

```
OLD_PASSWORD="nexus admin password"
NEW_PASSWORD="your new password"

curl -ifu admin:"${OLD_PASSWORD}" \
  -XPUT -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
  --data "${NEW_PASSWORD}" \
  <nexus base URL>/service/rest/v1/security/users/admin/change-password
```

## Screenshot of Nexus documentation

This documentation is only available on a running Nexus instance.  You can view this API on your own running Nexus instance by visiting:

- Menu: *System configuration  >  System > API*.

[image]

## Old way: Change password during initial onboarding

This only works during initial onboarding.   You should **definitely not use this method**.  Just documenting for completeness.

This section is for changing the initial password during onboarding.

Referencing Nexus source

- [Frontend code](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/7bff620450beea67d62d82831078d764378f22c4/plugins/nexus-onboarding-plugin/src/main/resources/static/rapture/NX/onboarding/step/ChangeAdminPasswordStep.js#L51)
- [Backend code](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/9b177ab50bd7f8470b08247b146da459170ecc8f/plugins/nexus-onboarding-plugin/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/onboarding/internal/OnboardingResource.java#L85-L99)

You can change the `admin` user password with a single `curl` command.

```
OLD_PASSWORD="initial nexus password"
NEW_PASSWORD="somepass"

curl -ifu admin:"${OLD_PASSWORD}" \
  -XPUT -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
  --data "${NEW_PASSWORD}" \
  <nexus base URL>/service/rest/internal/ui/onboarding/change-admin-password
```

Answer (score 0):

Sonatype Nexus has change-admin-password internal api to update the admin password, but its not straight forward to use, it's using the session id that's created with the /service/rapture/session endpoint.

```html
curl -v 'https://<hostname>/service/rapture/session' --data 'username=<base64 username>&password=<base64 password>'

curl -v -X PUT 'https://<hostname>/service/rest/internal/ui/onboarding/change-admin-password' -H 'cookie: <NXSESSIONID form the above response>' --data '<plain text password>'
```

Reference:
https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/9b177ab50bd7f8470b08247b146da459170ecc8f/plugins/nexus-onboarding-plugin/src/main/resources/static/rapture/NX/onboarding/step/ChangeAdminPasswordStep.js#L50

Answer (score 0):

Install the nexus3 cli:

```
pip install nexus3-cli
```

Get the first initial password (Assuming Nexus is running in docker):

```
docker exec nexus cat /nexus-data/admin.password
```

Set environment variables:

```
export NEXUS3_PASSWORD=<PASSWORD FROM PREVIOUS STEP>
export NEXUS3_USERNAME=<USERNAME>
export NEXUS3_URL=<URL>
```

Allow remote script execution by updating /nexus-data/etc/nexus.properties and appending the below line:

```
nexus.scripts.allowCreation=true
```

Restart nexus service to reload the last change:

```
docker container restart <nexus>
```

Create a file `reset-password.groovy` with the following contents (Thanks to @Dennis Hoer) :

```
def user = security.securitySystem.getUser('admin')
user.setEmailAddress('admin@mycompany.com')
security.securitySystem.updateUser(user)
security.securitySystem.changePassword('admin','admin456')
```

From command line create the script and run the script to reset the password of admin:

```
nexus3 script create --script-type groovy passreset reset-password.groovy
nexus3 script run passreset
```

---

The password is now reset